# Is it grammatically correct? Past Participle in to-infinitive

Tags: past-participles, to-infinitive

“Betrayal. That’s the first thing I feel, which is ludicrous. For there to be betrayal, there would have had to been trust first.”, The Hunger Games

I'm confused about **"... would have had to been trust first."** What kind of structure is this? Why is there a third form of a verb in a to-infinitive?

Comment: It might be worth comparing this to *"would have had to have been"*.

Comment: Is this from the book or the film? If the film, is it your transcript, or are you quoting someone else. If the book, which chapter?

Comment: @JamesK its from the book, at the very start of chapter 9, Part 1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an error in the book. The word "have" must be placed before "been". Errors like this in published books are rare, but they do happen occasionally.

Proofreading for this kind of mistake is difficult as your brain tends to "fill in the gaps" and include the word "have". One skill a proofreader needs is to read what is actually on the page, and not what you assume must be on the page.

Comment: James, I think this is actually a mishearing (and an authorial misrepresentation) of what AmE speakers actually say. As I mentioned in my downvoted answer, the speakers are saying  "had to *have* been" there but **have** is almost inaudible, *had tuv been*, as the "v" gets swallowed up by the "b" of "been".

Comment: OP states that this is quoted from the book.

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant by "authorial misrepresentation". Sorry if that was vague. The author of the book did not resort to "eye dialect" there, but had it been used, there could have been some indication that "have" is phonetically present, if only vestigially.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what is called the "Conditional Perfect" tense.

Which combines *would have* and the past participle of the main verb *had*. I think there is an implied verb which may be confusing you:

> For there to be betrayal, there would have had to **(have)** been trust first.

Answer (score 0):

**There would have had to *been*** is ungrammatical. **to been** is not a valid infinitive clause.

A native speaker might say

> ... there would have had *to've* been

or

> ... there woulda had to've been <sup>eye dialect</sup>

so that the 'v' is barely audible as it becomes the labial 'b' of "been".

> ... there woulda had tuv been ...  <sup>eye dialect</sup>

which can become:

> ... there woulda had toa been ... <sup>eye dialect</sup>

or

> > ... there woulda had tuh been ... <sup>eye dialect</sup>

the same process that produces **woulda** from "would have" yielding **toa** or **tuh** from "to have".

Comment: As always, anonymous downvotes are not instructive. There's either someone out there who doesn't know what he or she is talking about, or who knows more about this than I do but doesn't care to enlighten me.